# What is the Best Practice to update multiple fields in a Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a plugin registered in Post operation that needs to update multiple fields in CRM using data from an XML file. Currently I am using the following code:

```
                    if (node["node1"] != null)
                    {
                            var sId = sElement.GetElementsByTagName("pId")[0].InnerText;
                            Guid sGUID = new Guid(sId);
                            sEntity["Attrib1"] = sGUID;
                            service.Update(sEntity);
                    }

                    if (node["node2"] != null)
                    {
                            var sMax = sElement.GetElementsByTagName("pMax")[0].InnerText;
                            sEntity["Attrib2"] = sMax;
                            service.Update(sEntity);
                    }

                    if (node["node3"] != null)
                    {
                            var sMin = sElement.GetElementsByTagName("pMin")[0].InnerText;
                            sEntity["Attrib3"] = sMin;
                            service.Update(sEntity);
                    }
```

So I am calling the **service.Update** each time I need to update and in the above case 3 times.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do and call the **service.Update** only one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a single update in the end (eventually you can add a check in case none of the fields changed, to avoid a useless update):

```cs
  if (node["node1"] != null)
                    {
                            var sId = sElement.GetElementsByTagName("pId")[0].InnerText;
                            Guid sGUID = new Guid(sId);
                            sEntity["Attrib1"] = sGUID;
                    }

                    if (node["node2"] != null)
                    {
                            var sMax = sElement.GetElementsByTagName("pMax")[0].InnerText;
                            sEntity["Attrib2"] = sMax;
                    }

                    if (node["node3"] != null)
                    {
                            var sMin = sElement.GetElementsByTagName("pMin")[0].InnerText;
                            sEntity["Attrib3"] = sMin;
                    }
service.Update(sEntity);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Guido. I was doing that but I changeed it to update each attribute since I was getting an error. It ends up that the error is due to update an entity reference where I was updating it as an entity attribute.